# SplitViewController not work (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to make an application that supports SplitViewController.

But my application crashes on startup.

How can I fix this?

**MenuViewController** --> **ViewController** --> **DetailViewController**

AppDelegate.swift

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let splitViewController =  UISplitViewController()
        let menuViewController = MenuViewController()
        let homeViewController = ViewController()
        let secondViewController = DetailViewController()
        let menuNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:menuViewController)
        let homeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:homeViewController)
        let secondNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:secondViewController)
        splitViewController.viewControllers = [menuNavigationController,homeNavigationController,secondNavigationController]
        self.window!.rootViewController = splitViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    } else {
    }
    return true
}
```

**Error: (Example) - MenuViewController**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
    if isDarkMode == true {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 37/255, green: 38/255, blue: 39/255, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
    }
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

**My StoryBoard:**
[image]

Comment: tell us more how ti crashes

Comment: I get an error with everything related to the table - "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: this error has nothing to do with the code you showed here, nor with the splitViewController.. you are somewhere forcibly unwrapping an optional, and that crashes it.. show the code that crashes

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Check my edited question

Comment: do you define `MenuViewController` in storyboards?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ How can i make this???

Comment: show the rest of the `MenuViewController`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Set the initial view controller?

Comment: and tell us the exact line when this happens

Comment: Error on this point - self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)

Comment: OK, now add the whole `MenuViewController` to your question

Comment: All page with code??

Comment: all where there is `tableView` used anyhow

Comment: @MilanNosáľ https://filecloud.me/7tivbu7y5exs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you design your view controllers with storyboards, but you create them in code while effectively circumventing storyboards. That particular error happens because it was the responsibility of the storyboards to create the `tableView`, but now since you circumvented storyboards it is `nil`.

You have two options:

1. create the `splitViewController` in storyboards and use it as initial view controller of the app (and drop the programmatic creation of the splitViewController in appDelegate).
2. Get those view controllers from the storyboards, e.g.:

   ```
   let menuViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuController")
   ```

   In this I assume that the storyboard name is `"Main"`, and that you set the storyboard identifier of the `MenuViewController` is set to `"menuController"` - be careful, viewController's class (`MenuViewController`) is not the same thing as viewController's storyboard identifier (in my case I used '"menuController"'):

[image]

Do the same thing for all those view controllers that you created in storyboards.

Comment: Thank you)) But how can I deal with Split View with 3 VC?? MenuViewController --> ViewController --> DetailViewController

Comment: @B2Fq that's another question